# Null check for HttpHeaders in Angular 7

Tags: angular, http-headers, lazy-initialization

Recently, i am facing a weird issue, wherein i have the following piece of code which executes inside my interceptor, and at STEP 1, i am able to get req.headers, however when i reach STEP 2, i am getting an exception "Cannot Read property 'length' of null"

```
 private prepareUrlProperties(req: HttpRequest<any>) {
        let urlProperties = {};        
        if (req.headers) { // STEP 1
        try{
            const metaData = JSON.parse(req.headers.get('metadata') || '{}'); // STEP 2
        } catch (exp) {
           console.log(exp);
        }
            urlProperties = { ...urlProperties, ...metaData }; // STEP 3
        }
        return urlProperties;
    }
```

then, agaain at STEP 3, i can see all the keys in the same request with : "req.headers.keys()" or on hovering the request object.

I suspect, reason behind this is the **lazy Initialization** of headers, but how can i keep a safe check so i don't get any exception at runtime.

Following is the error :
[image]

PS: I have kept this check as well, but dint work :

```
 if (req.headers && req.headers.has('metadata'))
```

Need some adivce!

Attaching console.logs for req.headers , 1st is at step 1, 2nd is at step 3.

[image]

Comment: Can you `console.log(req.headers)` and share the output?

Comment: have attached screenshots for console.logs